# Is Intel Virtualization Technology for emulating android in eclipse

Tags: android, emulation

Hi I am getting error "Open HAX device failed" and on research on internet I realized "Intel Virtualization Technology" might be required for emulating android in eclipse. I have PC with Intel Pentium 4 CPU which does not support "Intel Virtualization Technology" is there a way to have android application emulated on such PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try enabling Intel VT-x from your system's BIOS. ([Here's a guide](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/speeding-up-the-android-emulator-on-intel-architecture))

If that doesn't work, just use an ARM (armeabi-v7a) image. You can download one from your SDK manager and then select it under the CPU/ABI option when creating your Android Virtual Device.

Answer (score 0):

Check [here](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology) to make sure your processor support Intel Virtualization technology. Without this hardware requirement it is not possible to HAXM to make your emulators run faster. HAXM working has nothing to do with Intel Atom x86 system images. It depends on the Virtualization technology supported by your processor.